# how to stop yaml parse/stringify removing !Equals and !Ref

Tags: yaml

In my node/typescript application, I have a yaml file in string format that I am modifying, so I am first using the `parse` function from the yaml library, making the edits and then turning it back to a string with `stringify` from the same yaml library. In my original yaml there exists the following line (the quotation marks and + are just due to the fact that it's in string format):

```
'IsFlagEnabled: !Equals [!Ref FlagEnabled, true]' +
```

However, after I use `parse`, make changes to the object (I'm just adding new properties and my changes don't have anything to do with the above line) and then use `stringify`, the above line then gets changed to:

```
'  IsFlagEnabled:\n' +

    '    - FlagEnabled\n' +

    '    - true\n' +
```

I do not wish for this change to happen - is there any way I can make sure the `'IsFlagEnabled: !Equals [!Ref FlagEnabled, true]' +`  line is unchanged? If not is there an alternative method using `parse`, modifying the JSON and using `stringify` again to make sure that I am able to make my desired changes to the yaml, without changing other parts involving `!Equals` and `!Ref`?

Comment: Quote the value

Comment: but the value is something that can be changed based on certain parameters that are passed in

Comment: Then dynamically construct the string, but still quote the value before passing it into the yaml encoder.

Comment: Really, if you want a more detailed answer, you're going to have to produce a minimal functional example that replicates the issue.